# How to change the option of couenne solver in Pyomo (in Colab)?

Tags: optimization, google-colaboratory, solver, pyomo, ipopt

I tried to change the option, feas_tolerance, of couenne solver (global solver of MINLP). I used Pyomo and Colab.

The solver is defined as follow:
_solver = SolverFactory(solver) = 'couenne'

Firstly, I set timelimit of the solver like:
results = _solver.solve(model, timelimit=10)

However, I got this outcome:
Command '['/content/bin/couenne', '/tmp/tmph_40xaou.pyomo.nl', '-AMPL']' timed out after 10.999969442000292 seconds

I guess it is too short to get a reasonable solution which satisfies the tolerance, so I tried to adjust the tolerance of couenne solver.
_solver.options['feas_tolerance'] = 10

However, I got this log:
ERROR:pyomo.opt:Solver (asl) returned non-zero return code (1)
ERROR:pyomo.opt:Solver log:
Couenne 0.5.8 -- an Open-Source solver for Mixed Integer Nonlinear Optimization
Mailing list: couenne@list.coin-or.org
Instructions: http://www.coin-or.org/Couenne
couenne: Unknown keyword "feas_tolerance"
Unknown keyword "feas_tolerance"

I used feas_tolerance because in their opt file, they specify it as feas_tolerance, but it does not work. How can I fix this?